# R tolower only within function

Tags: r, text, text-mining, tolower

I would like to remove words from a character vector. This is how I do:

```
library(tm)
words = c("the", "The", "Intelligent", "this", "This")
words_to_remove = c("the", "This")
removeWords(tolower(words), tolower(words_to_remove))
```

This is really nice, but I would like the word "Intelligent" to be returned as it was, meaning "Intelligent" instead of "intelligent.
Is there a possibility to use the function `tolower` only within the function `removeWords`?

Comment: From what package is the `removeWords` function, for those of us who are not familiar with it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is in `tm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use a base R approach with `grepl` here:

```
words_to_remove = c("the", "This")
pattern <- paste0("\\b", words_to_remove, "\\b", collapse="|")
words = c("the", "The", "Intelligent", "this", "This")

res <- grepl(pattern, words, ignore.case=TRUE)
words[!res]

[1] "Intelligent"
```

### Demo

The trick I use here is in my call to `paste` to generate the following pattern:

```
\bthe\b|\bThis\b
```

This pattern can, in a single regex evaluation, determine if any string in `words` is a match to be removed.

Comment: This is not exactly in line with the results from OP's output. I'd suggest `gsub(paste0("\\b", words_to_remove, "\\b", collapse="|"), "", words, ignore.case = TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you, nice solution but it gives me an error because I have apostrophes in my word_to_remove list like "i've". R says "invalid regular expression". Is it possible to have such words in the list?

Comment: Single apostrophe is not a regex metacharacter, and should not be causing an error.  I think you have some other problem with your data.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks for the comment.  I will leave my answer as is, as when I see a function called remove words, I expect it will remove them from my input.

Comment: Sure, that's up to you of course. Just note that your approach would potentially also remove other words, since it removes complete elements of the vector, not just single words. For instance, if one string was "the house" or similar.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I have overlooked a global variable which I definded earlier. This was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using base R's `%in%` function:

```
words = c("the", "The", "Intelligent", "this", "This")
words_to_remove = c("the", "This")

words[!(tolower(words) %in% tolower(words_to_remove))]
```

%in% returns TRUE for all cases where "words" are in the "words_to_remove" list.  Take the inverse for the words to keep.